# Search full string with different lengths in a char Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am working with an array with unknown length. I am looking for a string with a specific length that is given to me on the first two chars of the array. The array is filled with chars (hex values) and i am able to calculate the length of the first string, but i can't get the string nor get the next string length.

For example:

Buffer that reach to me from server:

```
var client = new net.Socket();
var res = Buffer.alloc(1);

client.on('data', function(data)){
     res = Buffer.from(data);
     console.log(res);
     var resArray = Array.from(res);
     resolveCommand(resArray);
});
```

`<Buffer 03 53 65 60 05 68 65 6c 6c 6f>`

I can calculate that the first string have 3 chars and the second got 5 chars, but for some reason i can't separate the strings ( the example above don't match reality, i could have 956 chars).
I need to store and print the strings for further use.

below I leave the code that isn't working until now.

responseBar is an array of chars that's why I need to convert it to string.

calcNumb(hexToDecimal(lengthName) is calculating the length of the string and it's working. I double it because I need pair of chars for the translation.

```js
const responseBar = ['0', '3', '5', '3', '6', '5', '6', '0', '0', '5', '6', '8', '6', '5', '6', 'c', '6', 'f']

 function hexToDecimal(datalength){                                                                      
     return parseInt(datalength, 16); 
 };

 function calcNumb(numberBytes){                                                       
    return Math.ceil((numberBytes * 6) /8);
 };
function resolveCommand(responseBar) {
  console.log(responseBar);
  var x = responseBar.toString();
  console.log('flag 1');
  for (var i = 0; i < responseBar.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log('flag 3');
    console.log("valor de i: " + i);
    var temp1 = responseBar[i];
    var temp2 = responseBar[i + 1];
    var lengthName = temp1 + temp2;
    var numbers = (calcNumb(hexToDecimal(lengthName)) * 2);
    console.log("NUMBER:  " + numbers);
    console.log('flag 3');
    console.log(lengthName);

  }
}

resolveCommand(responseBar)
```

Comment: hope this would help

Comment: It's working now. Sorry for the bother

Comment: What is expected output compared to what we see now?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but it could it be that you need to increment `i` by `numbers`, instead of by 1 (`i++`)? Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b1s3xo9p/)?

Comment: I am trying to parse all the strings. I tried your approach and it didn't solved the problem. I've done two for loops and solved half of the problems. Thanks for the help